# Why mapStateToProps do not map to the right prop?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, enzyme

I have this container

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createType, getTypes } from '../modules/type'

import Type from '../components/Type'

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  createType,
  getTypes
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  types: state.type.types
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Type)
```

and I would like to test it using `enzyme`. To do it, I'm using this test

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

import TypeContainer from 'routes/Type/containers/TypeContainer'

import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const mockStore = configureMockStore([ thunk ]);
const mockStoreInitialized = mockStore({
  type: {
    types: [
      {id: 1, name: 'type 1'}
    ]
  }
});

describe.only('(Route) Type', () => {
  it('should get container', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={mockStoreInitialized}>
        <TypeContainer />
      </Provider>
    )

    expect(wrapper.find(TypeContainer).prop('types')).to.deep.equal([{id: 1, name: 'type 1'}])
  })
})
```

The test is failing (at the assertion level) because `wrapper.find(TypeContainer).props()` is empty. I can not find find why.

The strange thing is that if I check the coverage report, my test passed into the `mapStateToProps` function.

Did I missed something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeContainer` won't have a prop called `types`, it will pull `types` from the store and pass it to `Type`, which *will* have a prop called `types`. So it's not that `mapStateToProps` is not doing the right thing; it's just you're making assertions against the wrong object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are totally right. If I import Type like this `import Type from 'routes/Type/components/Type'` and change the assertion to `expect(wrapper.find(Type).prop('types')).to.deep.equal([])` it is working